# Address boundary error - Why don't the nodes in my linked list get added properly?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, malloc

I'm trying to implement a linked list in C, however I can't seem to figure out how to append elements to the list.

```c
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct element {
    int value;
    struct element* next;
} element;

typedef struct list {
    element* head;
} list;

list* createList(int headValue) {
    list* L = malloc(sizeof(list));
    L->head = malloc(sizeof(element));
    L->head->value = headValue;
    L->head->next = NULL;
    return L;
}

// Returns the new length of the list
int appendToList(list* L, int value) {
    element* first = L->head;
    element* current = first;
    int length = 1;
    
    if (first == NULL) {
        printf("first is NULL\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    while (current != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
        length++;
    }
 
    current = malloc(sizeof(element));
    current->next = NULL;
    current->value = value;
    length++;

    return length;
}

// returns the value at index N (zero based)
//
// If the list has < N elements, returns -1 
int getAtIndexN(list* L, int N) {
    element* current = L->head;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        if (current->next == NULL) {
            printf("unable to get to index %d\n", i+1);
            exit(1);
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    return current->value;
}

int main(int args, char** argv) {
    int initvalues[] = {1,3,4,4};
    list* L = createList(5);
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        appendToList(L, initvalues[i]);
    }
    
    printf("element at index 1 has value %d\n", L->head->next->value);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm calling `appendToList` 4 times, in order to append the values from `initvalues` to the list, but only the head of the list seems to be added to the list correctly. the `printf` in `main` results in `'./a.out' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)`. I'm not sure if the issue lies in `appendToList` or somewhere else.

Comment: It seems that `while (current != NULL) {` should be `while (current->next != NULL) {` But there are more things to fix... Like `current = malloc(sizeof(element));` should be `current->next = malloc(sizeof(element));` and more.... (you should be able to fix it from here)

Comment: In the loop `while (current != NULL)`, `current` will eventually be null and you have lost the reference to the orginal list. Everything that follows, the allocation and assigments to `current?` happen in isolation and have no effect, other than leaking memory.

Comment: OT: Since you have a `struct list` (containing `head`) and you want to add to the end of the list, you should consider also having a `tail` pointer in `struct list`. It adds a little more control code but it makes appends much faster.

Comment: Looks like appendToList creates the new node but doesn't point anything to it (something->next = new_node).

Comment: OT: IMO it's a bad design that `createList` adds a first node to the list. It should only create an empty list, i.e. `L->head = NULL` In other words, your code should IMO be able to handle an empty list. Your current code doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 1):

In the loop `while (current != NULL)`, `current` will eventually be null and you have lost the reference to the original list. Everything that follows, the allocation and assignments to `current?` happen in isolation and have no effect, other than leaking memory.

It seems that `while (current != NULL) {` should be `while (current->next != NULL) {` But there are more things to fix... Like `current = malloc(sizeof(element));` should be `current->next = malloc(sizeof(element));` and so on.

PS: IMO it's a bad design that `createList` adds a first node to the list. It should only create an empty list, i.e. L->head = NULL In other words, your code should IMO be able to handle an empty list. Your current code doesn't allow that.

Comment: As you have admitted that much of this post is not your own work, you could consider making this answer into a [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/616624).